# function having its address passed as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I've tried this declaration:

```
using fp_type = void (*)(fp_type);
```

Unsurprisingly, it does not work.

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:13:26: error: expected ';' before '(' token                                                                                                                           
   using fp_type = void(*)(fp_type);                                                                                                                                        
                          ^                                                                                                                                                 
a.cpp:13:34: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token                                                                                                            
   using fp_type = void(*)(fp_type);
```

Is there a workaround? I was thinking about a `reinterpret_cast` from a dummy function pointer type, but I am not sure how standard-compliant that is. I am looking into this because I don't want to capture a lambda in a `::std::function`, and then use it recursively. I'd like to pass it a function pointer to itself.

Comment: You are defining `fp_type` recursively, which won't work.

Comment: I know. But a `reinterpret_cast` from/to a dummy function pointer type is still possible.

Comment: Huh? Is that last comment in reference to something that has since been deleted? because it makes zero sense in relation to the first comment in this chain.

Comment: @WhozCraig You don't understand? I am asking for a workaround and I even have proposed one. A pointer of a dummy function pointer type being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.2.10/6 guarantees you can `reinterpret_cast` a function pointer to a function pointer of different type, and when you cast it back to the original type, you get back the original pointer value.

I would prefer this:

```
void foo (struct foo_wrapper&);

struct foo_wrapper {
  void (*pf) (struct foo_wrapper&);
  // add constructor and accessor for convenience
};
```